# Calculate the probability $P(X \geq 1.9)$ where $X$ is a random variable with the dense function $f$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> $$\begin{equation*} f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{2}               
> & \text{ , if } 0 \leq x < 1\\
> -x^2+3x-\frac{3}{2}          & \text{ , if } 1 \leq x < 2\\ \frac{(3-x)^2}{2}            & \text{ , if } 2 \leq x < 3\\ 0         
> & \text{ , else } \end{cases} \end{equation*}$$
>
> Calculate the probability $P(X \geq 1.9)$ where $X$ is a random variable with the dense function $f$

In think we are supposed to calculate $$F(x) = P(X \geq 1.9) = \int_{1.9}^{\infty}f(x) \, dx$$

But how do you do this?

Is it just $$\int_{1.9}^{\infty}f(x) \, dx = \int_{1.9}^{1}\frac{x^2}{2} \, dx\, + \, \int_{1.9}^{2}-x^2+3x-\frac{3}{2} \, dx \, + \, \int_{1.9}^{3}\frac{(3-x)^2}{2} \, dx$$

?

Comment: Sorry but do you really think that $$\int_{1.9}^{\infty} = \int_{1.9}^{1}+ \int_{1.9}^{2}+ \int_{1.9}^{3}$$ is even *plausible*?

Comment: Did you meditate upon the answer you received [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2532225/)?

Comment: Why consider something that's not in your set, the first integral wont occur because you don't wan't to subtract the probability of $X<1.9$ so you just omit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that the lower bound of the first integral is smaller than the upper bound. This results in  negative values. This is a clear hint that something is wrong.

$$\int_{1.9}^{1}\frac{x^2}{2} \, dx=-0.9765$$

Another problem that the upper and lower bounds don´t match. You can say the next integral has to  begin where the last integral has ended. I colored the corresponding bounds to make it more clearly.

The integrals with the right upper and lower bounds are

$$P(X\geq 1.9)=P(1.9 \leq X < 2)+P(2 \leq X < 3)+P(X \geq 3 )$$

$$=\int_{1.9}^{\color{red}2} \left(-x^2+3x-\frac{3}{2} \right) \, dx\, + \, \int_{\color{red}2}^{3}\frac{(3-x)^2}{2} \, dx \, +0$$

Another approach is using the converse probability

$$P(X\geq 1.9)=1-P(X<1.9)=1-P(X<0)-P(0 \leq X <1)-P(1 \leq X < 1.9)$$

$$1-0-\int_{0}^{\color{red}1}\frac{x^2}{2} \, dx-\, \int_{\color{red}1}^{1.9}\left( -x^2+3x-\frac{3}{2} \right) \,  dx$$